# How to inject services into Play Framework 2.1 plugin?

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to write a plugin for Play Framework Java 2.1.1 and I would like to inject a service inside the plugin so I can unit test the plugin properly.

However, in the constructor I only have this.

```
public TestUsernamePasswordAuthProvider(Application app) {
    super(app);
}
```

which I think I cannot change I already have GlobalSettings to inject the services into controllers, can I do something like that for plugins?

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786666/is-there-a-nice-play2-way-of-injecting-instances-in-play-plugins-with-guice/27271047#27271047

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it's impossible see https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1389

but with some luck this [Pull Request](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1433) will be merge soon in the master.