# Is there a nice Play2 way of injecting instances in Play Plugins with Guice

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to figure out how to inject my classes with Google Guice into a play.api.Plugin.
I have implemented Guice to work with my controllers and it works great.

I use:

```
"com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.0-beta",
"com.tzavellas" % "sse-guice" % "0.7.1"
```

When a Controller instance is needed the getControllerInstance method in Global will load the appropriate implementation thanks to the injector.

**Global:**

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  /**
   * Currently we only want to load a different module when test.
   */
  private lazy val injector = {
    Logger.info("Is Test: "+Play.isTest)

    Play.isTest match {
      case true => Guice.createInjector(new TestModule)
      case false => Guice.createInjector(new CommonModule)
    }
  }    

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")
  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
  }

  override def getControllerInstance[A](clazz: Class[A]) = {
    Logger.info("getControllerInstance")
    injector.getInstance(clazz)
  }    
}
```

**Common:**

```
package modules

import com.tzavellas.sse.guice.ScalaModule
import services.{CallServiceImpl, CallService}

/**
 * User: jakob
 * Date: 11/5/13
 * Time: 10:04 AM
 */
class CommonModule extends ScalaModule {
  def configure() {
    bind[CallService].to[CallServiceImpl]
  }
}

class TestModule extends ScalaModule {
  def configure() {
    // Test modules!
  }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Singleton
class StatsController @Inject()(callService: CallService) extends Controller with securesocial.core.SecureSocial with ProvidesHeader  {

    def doSomething = {
        callService.call()
    }   
}
```

Now I would like to inject the same service into my Plugin, but I can't make use of the Global implementation since the plugins do not load with the **getControllerInstance**

```
class CallerPlugin (application: Application) extends Plugin {

  val secondsToWait = {
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    10 seconds
  }

  val defaultInterval = 60
  val intervalKey = "csv.job.interval"
  val csvParserEnabled = "csv.job.enabled"
  val newDir = "csv.job.new.file.path"
  val doneDir = "csv.job.done.file.path"

  var cancellable: Option[Cancellable] = None

  override def onStop() {
    cancellable.map(_.cancel())
  }

  override def onStart() {

    // do some cool injection of callService here!!!

    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
    val i = current.configuration.getInt(intervalKey).getOrElse(defaultInterval)

    cancellable = if (current.configuration.getBoolean(csvParserEnabled).getOrElse(false)) {
      Some(
        Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, i minutes) {
            callService.call()

        })
    } else None
  }
}
```

I guess there should be a way of implementing the injection in the onStart method somehow and there is probably some nice easy way of doing this but I can't figure it out. 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm interested in why you are using plugins? I only see how it complicates things.

Comment: Hello! Well I'm using plugins since I want to 1. make use of the onStart + Akka.system.scheduler.schedule 2. I want to build a pluggable registry of plugins so that I can insert the correct plugin depending on the state of a lead. DataProviderRegistry.dataProviders.get(lead.providerDependingOnState()) I'm influenced by SecureSocial and it's pluggable login provider system.

Comment: Point 2 sounds interesting. What is a DataProviderRegistry or a lead? Maybe you could direct me to some material?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jakob85/7581579 and a lead is an object that holds information about a company and some more stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're wondering how to instantiate and use a Guice injector. Well it's really simple:

```
val injector = Guice.createInjector(new CommonModule)
val callService = injector.getInstance(classOf[CallService])
```

And like that you have an instance of `CallServiceImpl`. If you look at your Global.scala, this is exactly what you do there. I haven't used Play plugins, so I'm not sure how you instantiate them, but I think a more idiomatic way would be, instead of putting it in plugin's `onStart`, to inject this `CallService` as a parameter to `CallerPlugin` (like you do for the controller). That way you could pass the responsibility of dependency injection down the tree, so that ideally you would end up with only one injector (probably in `Global`).

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. To inject Callservice into the CallerPlugin is exactly what I'm trying to do but I can't figure out how to do it =). As described I would like to use the Global somehow.

Comment: In global there is possibility to override onStart and onStop but how do I do the injection?

Comment: After reading up on play2 plugins, I don't see how you could pass arguments to a plugin's instantiation. It looks like plugins don't want to be dependent on your main logic, by nature. You probably can still get away with having each module "pull in" dependencies. Just paste those 2 lines from my answer into your plugin's `onStart`, where you put `// do some cool injection of callService here!!!`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found so far the best way to achieve this is to set plugin's dependency in `Global.onStart()`.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings{

    public Injector injector = createInjector();

    private Injector createInjector(){
        return Guice.createInjector(new SomeGuiceModule());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {
        CallerPlugin plugin = application.plugin(CallerPlugin.class);
        plugin.setCallService(injector.getInstance(CallService.class));
    }
}
```

Make sure that plugin number is lower that `10000`. Global has `10000`, so, your plugin will be started before `Global.onStart()` gets called.